# Retrieving elements from a class

Tags: python

```
class Foo():
  def __init__(self, implementations):
       self.implementations = {'foo': self.foo, 'bar': self.bar}

  def foo(self, val):
      return np.sin(val)

  def bar(self,val):
      return np.cos(val)
```

Now, I want to access the above as

```
f = Foo()
f['foo'] = #returns sin function??
f['bar'] = # returns cos function??
f['baz'] = # raises an error?
f['all'] = # returns the functions in self.implementations
```

I feel, there should be a way to do this in python but am not able to think how...

Comment: What about `f.foo()` ?

Comment: [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) allows you to implement the `f[]` method.

Comment: @ForceBru: that behaves normally.. though I think of them as bonus?? Maybe I will annotate these methods as private with underscore?

Comment: do you want to be able to do `f['foo']` and have it actually call the `foo` method?

Comment: @Fraz, what are _private methods_? There are no such methods in Python, no?

Comment: @reptilicus: I am thinking more like 

x = 20
values = [ func(x) for func in func['all']]

Comment: @ForceBru names with a leading underscore are private-by-convention, and those with two are name-mangled.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, but everyone can call any of them without problems. Such as `f.__init__()`. They're not as _private_ as in C++.

Comment: @ForceBru: yeah.. but think of it as a convention:

"The main convention for private properties and implementation details is to prefix all “internals” with an underscore. If the client code breaks this rule and accesses these marked elements, any misbehavior or problems encountered if the code is modified is the responsibility of the client code"
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/

Comment: Well the leading-and-trailing-double-underscore methods are special *"magic methods"* that implement built-in behaviour - you would rarely call e.g. `__init__`, `__str__`, etc. outside the class (you'd use `Class()`, `str(instance)`, etc.). They aren't **protected** as they are in some languages, no, but *"we're all consenting adults here"*!

Comment: Two words, operator overloading.

Comment: You can get an object's attributes by string with `getattr(f, 'foo')`, which would return the `foo` function. There are several methods that get included with new classes by default (such as `__module__` and `__ne__`), so you'd have to specify which ones you want, perhaps by filtering out the ones that start and end with `__`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are looking for. Maybe that's UserDict

```
import UserDict

class Foo(UserDict.UserDict):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        UserDict.UserDict.__init__(self, data if data is not None else {})
```

In the end you are really just using this as a dictionary. So why not just use a dictionary if that makes things easier.